# Where to define global constants in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, constants

I have several partial views which all has common class `div` tags.

e.g.

PView1.cshtml

```
<div class="awesome">Part of PView1 html</div>
```

PView2.cshtml

```
<div class="awesome">Part of PView1 html</div>
```

Some of these shared values are concatenated to a dynamic data from model:

```
<div id="someId + @Model.Id"></div>
```

I would like to move these constants to one place.

Where should I place global constants in ASP.NET MVC  ?
Static class?

Comment: Static class or resource file most likely.

Comment: Another option would be to use a base model from which the others would inherit.

Comment: Use a static class and extend the set of Html helpers

Answer (score 2):

You can use static class with static properties or public const variables to handle your constants. But i recommend you use web.config or a custom xml config file to store your constant string and then write a static class to access them.

Comment: Why do you recommend that way ?

Comment: Custom XML config file will not give me intelli sense advantages, I don't want a user to change these strings, its not a configuration that should go to to web.config.

Comment: User can not change your config files(*.config). If you create a static class with static properties to access your constants you will have intelli sense in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I patched this together from other answers that didn't seem to put it all together, so to stand on the shoulders of giants...

1. Right-click on project
2. Add ASP.NET Folder App_LocalResources
3. Right-click on App_LocalResources
4. Add Resources File
5. Add Resource1.resx
6. Define Names/Values
7. Right-click on Resource1.resx file and select Properties

   Ensure they are as follows:

   - Build Action: Embedded Resource
   - Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
   - Custom Tool Namespace: Resources

You can reference these values in the View like this:

```
@Resources.Resource1.String1
```